# JavaScript algorithm: print out the path from directed graph with minimal costs

Tags: javascript, algorithm, breadth-first-search, directed-graph

Here is a problem that can be modeled using a directed graph with different costs on each edge.

Our input is an array of edges.

```js
const edges = [['A', 'B', 20], ['B', 'C', 10], ['A', 'C', 50], ['B', 'D', 5], ['D', 'C', 2]]
```

`['A', 'B', 20],` meaning that from `A` to `B` the cost is 20. I wanted  to write a function that returns the path between a given place to another place which has the minimal cost. Note that there is **no cycles** in this graph.

In this case, if the starting place is `A` and the destination is `C` then there are three ways to go

```
path 1: A => C - cost 50
path 2: A => B => C - cost 30
path 3: A => B => D => C - cost 27
```

so the function should return the path that has the minimal cost which is `A, B, D, C`

Here is my attempt:

```js
function bar(edges, start, end) {
    const paths = []
    const visited = new Map()
    const graph = edges.reduce((map, [start, end, cost]) => {
        if(map.has(start)) {
            map.get(start).push([end, cost])
        } else {
            map.set(start, [[end, cost]])
        }
        return map
    }, new Map())
    const queue = [[start, 0]]
    for(const [node, costSofar] of queue) {
        if(node === end) {
            let pointer = node
            const path = []
            while(pointer) {
                path.push(pointer)
                pointer = visited.get(pointer)
            }    
            
            paths.push([path.reverse().join(','), costSofar])
            continue
        }
        graph.get(node).forEach(([dest, localCost]) => {
            // this part  is problematic
            visited.set(dest, node)
            queue.push([dest, localCost + costSofar])
            
        })
    }

    return paths.sort(([pathA, costA], [pathB, costB]) => costA - costB)[0]
}
```

So I use an adjacency list to represent the graph, i.e.

```
{
    A: [['B', 20], ['C', 50]]
    B: [['C', 10], ['D', 5]]
    D: [['C', 2]]
}
```

and then I use breadth first search to explore the graph and record the path and once we arrive at our destination we add the path to `paths`. Btw I am aware of Dijkstra algorithm, but, correct me if I am wrong, I feel like since this graph doesn't have a cycle so we can use a normal bfs to solve it.

My question is, my function actually has a bug where although it does capture all of the paths with its corresponding cost but the paths are not 100% correct. If you log out the return statement of the function i.e. `paths.sort(([pathA, costA], [pathB, costB]) => costA - costB)` you will see the value here is  `[ [ 'A,B,D,C', 27 ], [ 'A,B,C', 30 ], [ 'A,B,C', 50 ] ]`  . The first two are correct but the last one should be `['A','C', 50]`. I think the problem is caused by the way to populate `visited` map but I cannot figure out how I can fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because you want to maintain separate path information for each possible path, even when one path intercepts another later, having a `visited` Map where the keys are destination nodes won't do the trick, since `visited.set` will overwrite previous paths' information.

Instead of using the `visited` to get the pointer in the loop at the end, I'd get the node info for the `graph` Map instead while iterating. Recursion will help.

```js
function bar(edges, start, end) {
    const graph = edges.reduce((map, [start, end, cost]) => {
        if(map.has(start)) {
            map.get(start).push([end, cost])
        } else {
            map.set(start, [[end, cost]])
        }
        return map
    }, new Map())
    const paths = [];
    const find = (start, pathSoFar = [start], costSoFar = 0) => {
        for (const [dest, cost] of graph.get(start)) {
            const newPath = pathSoFar.concat(dest);
            if (dest === end) {
                paths.push([newPath.join(','), costSoFar + cost]);
            } else {
                find(dest, newPath, costSoFar + cost);
            }
        }
    };
    find(start);
    
    console.log(paths);
    
    // return paths.sort(([pathA, costA], [pathB, costB]) => costA - costB)[0]
    // or, make it O(n) instead of O(n log n):
    return paths.reduce((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? b : a);
}
const edges = [['A', 'B', 20], ['B', 'C', 10], ['A', 'C', 50], ['B', 'D', 5], ['D', 'C', 2]]

console.log(bar(edges, 'A', 'C'));
```

Comment: Yea indeed. using dfs instead of bfs is better suited here!